# wordpress pages tab in custom theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm learning wordpress and I have created a simple template using basic HTML/CSS.

Everything works so far but I cannot figure out how to display the Page's Tabs that I created from my wp admin panel on my header.php.

my current static HTML code for the tabs looks like this:

```
<div id="profile-navigation" class="navbar profile-navigation">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
       <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Blog/a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I tried to do this:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="">
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but that doesn't really make sense and even though it displays the Pages Tabs successfully, they have no style and they are all over the place on my page!

Could someone please offer me some advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do not wrap it with `li` and `a` then

Comment: @MaciejKwas, it doesn't really matter to be honest. still all over the place but `<li><a href="">Home</a></li>` and `<li><a href="">Blog</a></li>` display properly!! is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You know, there's a magic button called `F12`, hit it, check how the structure looks like and you will realize why there are no styles. First shot: there's automatic wrapping ul, so you have `ul`'s doubled

Comment: So basically I need to style whats wordpress's given me and I cannot use my own tabs?

Comment: You can, you just have to read the documentation how to achieve certain things

Comment: Can you please post the CSS or add a fiddle or a link to your site?

Comment: Big question: How did you create said 'tabs'. Plugin? Incomplete functions.php code?

Comment: @Nooneknows, No one knows! kidding, I'm just editing the twentytwelve template!

Comment: @DigitalBrent, the CSS is huge and fiddle it no good because I'm working on wordpress!

Comment: You don't need to post ALL the CSS. Just the styles related to this question... Anything is better than nothing. I develop in WordPress all the time. You can copy and paste code directly into the fiddle. That's another case where you don't need all the code, just the parts that are relevant to the question.

Comment: I understand what you mean.. even though this is the first time I'm using wordpress and it made me hate it even more,  I use jsfiddle all the time! like i said, the CSS related to this question is huge! I think I'm gonna give up on wordpress as its not really my thing any way... i'm more comfortable to develop sites from scratch using core PHP... wordpress can jog on :)

Comment: Yes, WordPress can be a headache. I'd encourage you not to give up on it though. It may slow you down for a while but in the long run it will save you time. Please see the edits I made to your question. Since this question will remain on SO for a long time it would be a good idea to apply the edits in order to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and next time- read the docs

```
$defaults = array(
    'menu_class'      => 'nav',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Comment: still the same i'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** First off, your `<ul>` tags don't match. You need to close them with `</ul>` not just `<ul>`.

Use wp_nav_menu to dynamically display navigation pages that you've put into a menu in WordPress. [Documentation can be found here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Basically, you'll want to add this code for the menu instead of typing it out in HTML:

```
$defaults = array(
    'menu_class'      => 'nav',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

The menu can then be styled by targeting the `.nav` class or any of it's children, in the CSS. For example if you want to style the links, you should be able to do:

```
.nav li a{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it prints out something like this: `<div class="nav"><ul><li class="current_page_item"><a href="somepage.hp">Home</a></li>` but my HTML code is totally different and class `nav` is not a Div and it is a `<ul>`.

Comment: You should be able to style it either way. I can see no reason why the code from your comment doesn't work. The issue you are having may be somewhere else. Could you post a link to the site or like a fiddle or something so I can take a look at the code?

Comment: Please also see my edit. Your closing ul tags need a slash in front of them.

Comment: sorry I'm not entirely sure what you've edited! but as far as I can see, my code has a </ul> closing tag so that is not the problem! the problem is that with your code you are trying to give a CSS style to a Div with a class 'nav' but in my design nav is a ul and not a div.

Comment: It doesn't matter to the CSS. It will still apply the styles whether it's a div, a ul, or an h1. If it has that class it will take on whatever styling is not excluded by the natural traits of that element.